# Creating table valued function in mysql workbench getting error "not valid position,expecting identifier"

Tags: mysql

```
Create function select_gender(@gender as varchar(50)) 
returns table
as
return(select * from employee where gender=@gender);
```

i'm getting error at first line @gender("not valid position")

How to sort this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The function definition you provided is written in SQL Server syntax, not MySQL syntax.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE select_gender(IN gender_val VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM employee
    WHERE gender = gender_val;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

n the code above, we use a stored procedure instead of a table-valued function. The procedure takes an input parameter **gender_val**, and it directly returns the result set based on the **gender** column condition.

To use this procedure, you can call it like this:

```
CALL select_gender('Male');
```